# Delete duplicates using a group and having

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-delete

This is my first post. I have see similar questions asked but didn't understand the answer. I apologies if this has been posted before.

I have an issue where a calendar sync has duplicated a bunch of appointments. I want to delete all the appointments except the original. I put the sql together below to group the appointments. But I am unable to delete from the group and I tried to Sub query but you cant have multiple columns.

The Table is called Appts. I was going to use the reminder time to separate the original from the dupes.

Attempt 1:

```
select startdate, starttime, subject, count(*) 
from appts 
group by startdate, starttime, subject 
having count (*) > 3
```

Attempt 2:

```
DELETE FROM appts
WHERE subject IN (Select startdate, starttime, subject, count(*) 
                 from appts 
                 group by startdate, starttime, subject 
                 having count (*) > 3)
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  Your actual _database_ is something like MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: My apologies I'm using Advantage database sql engine.  It is a little limited compared to sql server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cte like below (if your dbms sql server)

```
with cte as
(
select startdate, starttime, subject, count(*) from appts 
group by startdate, starttime, subject having count (*) > 3
) delete from cte
```

Comment: How do you know the OP is using SQL Server?